# React-Native, How to add a View on the top of an alert or actionsheetIOS?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I want to add a View to cover my entire app.
details: Whenever AppState changes (to inactive or background), lock screen should appear to hide app contents and user should enter passcode to unlock it.

However, in IOS, dialogs from "Alert, ActionSheetIOS, Share" are on the top of everything.
As a result, my LockedView cannot cover these.
Is there a way to create cover these dialogs?

Below is the simple example code for reproducing my case.

(App.js)

```
import React, {Component} from "react"
import {
  Alert,
  AppState,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from "react-native"

export default class extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    AppState.addEventListener("change", this._handleAppStateChange)
    this.state = {
      isLocked: false
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe()
    AppState.removeEventListener("change", this._handleAppStateChange)
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    const isLocked = nextAppState !== "active"
    this.setState({isLocked})
  }

  onPressAlert () {
    Alert.alert("alert")
  }

  renderContent () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.content}>
        <Text>UNLOCKED</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPressAlert}>
          <Text>Alert</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }

  renderLockedView (isLocked) {
    return isLocked ?
      <View style={styles.locked}><Text>LOCKED</Text></View> : null
  }

  render() {
    const {isLocked} = this.state

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.renderContent()}
        {this.renderLockedView(isLocked)}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  content: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "green",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  locked: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    backgroundColor: "red",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
})
```

With this code, app can cover contents(green) with lockedView(red) but alert.
I want to position lockedView on the top of alert.

Comment: You can't dismiss the alert unless user interacts, instead of the default alert create your own modal for alert and then you can hide it when needed.\

Comment: @Fawaz Dismissing or hiding dialogs is one way to achieve my goal.
But, It is a more direct way to render a "View" covering the entire screen (without dismissing the alert), and I need some advice.